# Binding an RxJava Observable to a TextView's text property

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-binding

Is there a way, perhaps using RxBinding, to bind an `Observable<String>` to a `TextView` object such that its `.text` property is kept up to date with the `Observable`? Obviously, you could `subscribe()` and manually update the text field, but a convenience method seems likely. I just can't find it, and the documentation hasn't yielded any answers for me.

A similar convenience method exists in `RxSwift` (or rather `RxCocoa`), in case that clarifies what I am asking for; it's called `.bindTo()` there.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but have you seen the Android Data Binding library: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes methods like this is presented in rx-binding library.
For example for TextView `RxTextView.text(textView)` creates action which can be used as subscriber.

See [source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/1.0.0/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding/widget/RxTextView.java#L167)

Usage would be something like this

```
observable.subscribe(RxTextView.text(textView), Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

Be careful with memory and read docs:

> *Warning:* The created observable keeps a strong reference to view. Unsubscribe to free this reference.

It is not the same as `bindTo` magic but doing what you need.